# fixed url on address bar - show only base url http://www.mysite.com

Tags: apache, url

I need to show on the address bar just the first part of the url of my site.

For example for any page with name like

`http://www.mysite.com/mypage.php` or 
everything else

I want to see just `http://www.mysite.com` on the address bar of the browser.

How this can be achieved?

I tried with apache `RewriteRule` but with no result.

Comment: So as you say, if you access mypage.php, it should load the page but the url should not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from being a really bad idea for people actually trying to use your site, there is no way you can do this on the server side, because the server needs to know which page was accessed - that's what a URL is for. What you are looking for is to make it *appear to the user* that they are still at the same URL.

This is easy enough if you put your entire site in an HTML frameset with one frame, or an iframe sized to fill the browser window. This does require all external links to have `target="_top"`, and without additional JS people can break out of the frame and access the pages individually anyway.

An alternative approach, that will only work on some browsers, would be to use [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FManipulating_the_browser_history) to fake the address bar back to `/` every time a new page loads.